# How to count the number of objects in a given foreign key in django inside the html template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have 3 models which are.

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Subcategory(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my Html template I want to access the number of items in each given category. I have tried using the _set method but it doesn't work on `category.subcategory_set.course_set.count`. How can I access the number of courses under each given category. I didn't include category as a foreign key in my Items models as it can lead to assignment of wrong category-subcategory pair for an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't do this in a template. Django's template langauge is delibrately restricted, to prevent people from writing business logic in the template. Furthermore even if that was possible, it would be inefficient due to an *N+1* problem.

You can count the number of items per category by defining a queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(
    num_items=Count('subcategory__item')
)
```

The `Category` objects that arise from *this* queryset, will have an extra attribute `.num_items` that contains the total number of items related to a `Subcategory` that is related to *that* `Category`.